# How to encapsulate $scope in Angular.Js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have a pattern, which I want to use twice, but with different values. For example:

```
 .directive("day", function($scope){
     return {
        template: '<div>{{day}}</div>'
        }
    }
```

Can I use it in two another directive, but encapsulate 'day' to see result like that:

```
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
```

Especially if I want to keep binding value of all 'day'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you meant something like this?

```js
app.directive('day', function(){
  return {
    scope: {
      dayValue: '='
    },
    template: '<div>{{dayValue}}</div>'
  }
})

app.directive('outerDirective', function(){
  return {
    link: function($scope){
      $scope.days = [1,2,3];
    },
    template: '<day day-value="day" ng-repeat="day in days"></day>'
  }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

What you want is called an "isolate" scope where you bind an attribute of the directive from the local "isolate" scope to the parent scope.

```
app.directive('day', function(){
  return {
    scope: {
      day: '='
    },
    template: '<div>{{day}}</div>'
  }
})
```

HTML

```
    <div ng-init="day1='Thursday'; day2='Friday'">

        <div day="day1"></div>
        <div day="day2"></div>

    </div>
```

Result

```
Thursday

Friday
```

For more on directive scopes see the [AngularJS $compile API Reference -- scope](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-scope-).

Comment: Thank you, that help me)