# How do I make an angularJS directive that returns a different template based on the arguments sent to it?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

In my first experiment, I have the following in my angulerJS template:

```
LoremIpsum: {{myObj.a}}
```

This works. The value of myObj.a is displayed because in my controller(`myController`), I have set $skope.myObj = `<something with attribute a>`

But next experiment, I want to have an element directive that looks at the value `myObj.A` and display different things based on that value. The logic of that decision is fairly complex, so I want to put it in the directive, not the template.

So here is my new template:

```
LoremIpsum: <a-directive a="myObj.a">
```

Here is what my current directive looks like:

```
.directive('aDirective',function(){
    return {
      restrict:'E',
      template: 'a={{myObj.a}}'
    };
  }
)
```

This directive displays the value of `a`. But it has problems:

1. Why must I use `myObj.a` inside the directive instead of just `a`? I just passed it in? I need to use the value of the argument to the function, not something that is attached to the controller. How do I do that?
2. I want to change the value of `template` based on the value of `a`. How can I do it?

I need the value of the argument `a` that is being passed in but I can't get it in the body of the directive. That's what I need. How??

Comment: Look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34693687/5535245) where I explain isolate scopes and passing directive attributes to them.

Answer (score 1):

> 1. Why must I use myObj.a inside the directive instead of just a? I just passed it in? I need to use the value of the argument to the
>      function, not something that is attached to the controller. How do I
>      do that?

By using a `scope`:

```
app.directive('aDirective',function() {
    return {
        restrict:'E',
        scope: {
            a: '='
         },
         template: 'a={{a}}'
     };
});
```

> 2. I want to change the value of template based on the value of a. How can I do it?

By using a `link`:

```
app.directive('aDirective',function(){
    return {
        restrict:'E',
        scope: {
            a: '='
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            // here scope.a will give you the value of the a attribute
            // as passed from the parent
            if (scope.a == 'foo') {
                scope.contentUrl = 'foo.html';
            } else {
                scope.contentUrl = 'bar.html';
            }
        },
        template: '<div ng-include="contentUrl"></div>'
    };
});
```

Obviously inside your `foo.html` and `bar.html` templates you will have access to `{{a}}`.

Comment: Thanks! I can now see the contents of `foo.html` and `bar.html` displayed. but in them, when I do `{{a}}`, it shows nothing. I inserted `console.log('a = ', skope.a);` into the first line of the `link` function and it showed me `undefined`. Even when I pass in an integer literal, it still shows undefined here.

Answer (score 0):

> Why must I use myObj.a inside the directive instead of just a?

Because your directive doesn't do anything with the argument it receives. Use an isolate scope:

```
.directive('aDirective',function(){
    return {
      restrict:'E',
      scope: {
          a: '@'
      }
      template: 'a = {{ a }}'
    };
  }
)
```

> I want to change the value of template based on the value of a. How can I do it?

The same way you would do in a controller: using ng-show of ng-if, for example:

```
.directive('aDirective',function(){
    return {
      restrict:'E',
      scope: {
          a: '@'
      }
      template: '<span ng-if="a.length > 10"><em>{{ a }}</em> is a long string</span>'
                + ' <span ng-if="a.length <= 10"><em>{{ a }}</em> is a short string</span>
    };
  }
)
```